# Can I use a string as a name in Visual Basic to change an objects properties?

Tags: string, vb.net, variables

My Idea is not too hard. I have a button, a string called "progname", a TextBox and three Progressbars.

When I enter a number into the TextBox and press the button, the following code run's through.

```
Dim progname As String
    progname = "Progressbar" & TextBox1.Text
```

Now I have a string called "progname" with relevant value.For an example "Progressbar2".

What I want to achieve is write something like:

```
progname.Value += 1
```

Which can't be done, as "Value" is not a Member of "String". How can I do this? 
Overall what I want, is to be able to select one of the three progressbars by typing one of the numbers 1-3 into the TextBox and then change that ones porperties.

Comment: a string "progressbar" is not the same as an object reference. If you know the name of the control you could fish it out of the controls collection.   Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Don't let a user type in a number in the hope that there is a control that actually exists with that number at the end of the name. This sounds like a question where a bit more detail about what you're really trying to achieve would have been good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

A basic example is this, which searches your form for controls with the name matching your string. It then changes the type to a `ProgressBar` so you can access all the methods ..

```
Dim progbar As ProgressBar = CType(Me.Controls.Find(progName, False)(0), ProgressBar)
progbar.Value += 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I was playing around with something like that but couldn't really get it to work. This one works great!